# how to check what Path was clicked in canvas android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas

I'm doing a Canvas to draw a squares on a board in Canvas in Android Studio,

I need to know what path was clicked in my `onTouchEvent`

but all i can take out from there is an `event.x and event.y,`

because I have a pretty complicated shape it will be very hard to calculate only based on x and y what path was clicked.

Is there another way I can check the clicked path on the screen ?

Here is my canvas:

```
public class PianoKeysWidget extends View {

    public class ChessSlice extends Path {
        public ChessSlice() {
            key = "C";
            octave = 0;
            isKeyBlack = false;
        }

        public String key;
        public int octave;
        public boolean isKeyBlack;

    }

    Paint WhiteKeyPaint, BlackKeyPaint, OuterRimPaint;
    Boolean isTouching = false;
    float touchY, touchX;
    int globalKeyWidth = 20;
    PianoKeysInterface mainInterface;
    ChessSlice framePath;
    ArrayList<ChessSlice> pianoPathsArray = new ArrayList<ChessSlice>();

    int width = 340; // default numbers until the screen will change it when it gets the actuall view
    int height = 1200; // default numbers until the screen will change it when it gets the actuall view


    String TAG = "alignmentWidget";

    /**
     * construuctor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public PianoKeysWidget(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.postInvalidate();

        init();
    }

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public PianoKeysWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.postInvalidate();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();

        init();
    }

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyleAttr
     */
    public PianoKeysWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.postInvalidate();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private static Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, int drawableId) {
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableId);
        } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
            return getBitmap((VectorDrawable) drawable);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type");
        }
    }


    //////////////////////////////////
    //////////////On Draw//////////////
    //////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_accessibility_black_24dp);


        if (pianoPathsArray.size() == 0) { // initlizes the init
            init();
        }

        // draws the first circle
        ////////////////////////////////////////////

        //go through the array and paints the corisponding cells
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        for (int i = 0; i < pianoPathsArray.size(); i++) {

            canvas.drawPath(pianoPathsArray.get(i), WhiteKeyPaint);

            if (pianoPathsArray.get(i).isKeyBlack) {
                canvas.drawPath(pianoPathsArray.get(i), BlackKeyPaint);
            }

            canvas.drawPath(pianoPathsArray.get(i), OuterRimPaint);



//            if (pianoPathsArray.get(i).color.equals("white")) {
//                canvas.drawPath(pianoPathsArray.get(i), WhiteKeyPaint);
//            } else {
//                canvas.drawPath(pianoPathsArray.get(i), BlackKeyPaint);
//            }
//
//
//
//            //draw the queens
//            if (pianoPathsArray.get(i).isOcupied) {
//                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, pianoPathsArray.get(i).centerX - 40, pianoPathsArray.get(i).centerY - 45, BlackKeyPaint);
//            }

        }



        //draw the frame
        canvas.drawPath(framePath, OuterRimPaint);

    }

    private void activateErrorAnimationTimer(final ChessSlice chessSlice) {

    }


    private void init() {

        if (pianoPathsArray.size() > 0) { // initlizes the init
            return;
        }

        //gets teh width and height, initlized only after ondraw happend so it wouldn't be 0 0
        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();

        //defining paints
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        WhiteKeyPaint = new Paint();
        WhiteKeyPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightKeyColor));
        WhiteKeyPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        BlackKeyPaint = new Paint();
        BlackKeyPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkKeyColor));
        BlackKeyPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        OuterRimPaint = new Paint();
        OuterRimPaint.setStrokeWidth(10f);
        OuterRimPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        OuterRimPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        // applyes hardware Acceleration
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, BlackKeyPaint);
        }

        int overAllKeys = Globals.getInstance().numberOfPianoKeys;

        int numberWhiteKeys = getWhiteKeysCount(overAllKeys)-1;
        int numberBlackKeys = getBlackKeysCount(overAllKeys);

        Log.d ("testings", "whitekeys: "+numberWhiteKeys);
        Log.d ("testings", "blackKeys: "+numberBlackKeys);

        // gets the main slices paths
        ///////////////////////////////////////////

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberWhiteKeys; i++) {
            pianoPathsArray.add(getSlicesPathsWhite(i, numberWhiteKeys));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberBlackKeys; i++) {
            pianoPathsArray.add(getSlicesPathsBlack(i, numberBlackKeys, numberWhiteKeys));
        }

        //draw frame
        framePath = new ChessSlice();
        framePath.moveTo(0, 0);
        framePath.lineTo(width, 0);
        framePath.lineTo(width, height);
        framePath.lineTo(0, height);
        framePath.lineTo(0, 0);

    }

    private int getBlackKeysCount(int overAllKeys) {
        int allKeys = overAllKeys;
        int blackKeys = 0;

        while (allKeys > 12) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 5;
            allKeys = allKeys - 12;
        }

        if (allKeys == 12) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 5;
        } else if (allKeys == 11) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 5;
        } else if (allKeys == 10) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 4;
        }else if (allKeys == 9) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 4;
        }else if (allKeys == 8) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 3;
        }else if (allKeys == 7) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 3;
        }else if (allKeys == 6) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 2;
        }else if (allKeys == 5) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 2;
        }else if (allKeys == 4) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 2;
        }else if (allKeys == 3) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 1;
        }else if (allKeys == 2) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 1;
        }else if (allKeys == 1) {
            blackKeys = blackKeys + 0;
        }

        return blackKeys;
    }

    private int getWhiteKeysCount(int overAllKeys) {
        int allKeys = overAllKeys;
        int whiteKeys = 0;

        while (allKeys > 12) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 7;
            allKeys = allKeys - 12;
        }

        if (allKeys == 12) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 8;
        } else if (allKeys == 11) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 7;
        } else if (allKeys == 10) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 6;
        }else if (allKeys == 9) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 6;
        }else if (allKeys == 8) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 5;
        }else if (allKeys == 7) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 5;
        }else if (allKeys == 6) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 4;
        }else if (allKeys == 5) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 3;
        }else if (allKeys == 4) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 2;
        }else if (allKeys == 3) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 2;
        }else if (allKeys == 2) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 1;
        }else if (allKeys == 1) {
            whiteKeys = whiteKeys + 1;
        }

        return whiteKeys;
    }

    public ChessSlice getSlicesPathsWhite(int i, int numberWhiteKeys) {

        int KeyWidth = width / numberWhiteKeys;
        int rowHeight = height;

        int startX = 0+(i*KeyWidth);
        int startY = 0;

        ChessSlice segmentPath = new ChessSlice();
        segmentPath.moveTo(startX, startY);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX+KeyWidth, startY);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX+KeyWidth, startY+rowHeight);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX, startY+rowHeight);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX, startY);

        segmentPath.key = getCorrectKeyForNumber(i);
        segmentPath.octave = getCorrectOctavForNumber(i);
        segmentPath.isKeyBlack = false;

        return segmentPath;
    }


    public ChessSlice getSlicesPathsBlack(int i, int numberBlackeys, int numberWhiteKeys) {

        int KeyWidth = width / numberWhiteKeys;
        int rowHeight = height/2;

        int modifierForBlackKeys = getBlackKeyModifier(i);

        int startX = (KeyWidth/2)+(i*KeyWidth)+(modifierForBlackKeys*KeyWidth);
        int startY = 0;

        ChessSlice segmentPath = new ChessSlice();
        segmentPath.moveTo(startX, startY);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX+KeyWidth, startY);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX+KeyWidth, startY+rowHeight);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX, startY+rowHeight);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX, startY);

        segmentPath.key = getCorrectBlackKeyForNumber(i);
        segmentPath.octave = getCorrectBlackOctavForNumber(i);
        segmentPath.isKeyBlack = true;

        return segmentPath;
    }

    private int getBlackKeyModifier(int i) {
        int modifier = 0;
        if (i >= 10) {
            modifier = 4;
        }else if (i >= 7) {
            modifier = 3;
        } else if (i >= 5) {
            modifier = 2;
        } else if (i >= 2) {
            modifier = 1;
        }
        return modifier;
    }

    private String getCorrectKeyForNumber (int number) {

        int functionNum = number;
        String key = "C";

        while (functionNum > 6) {
            functionNum = functionNum - 7;
        }

        if (functionNum == 0) {
            key = "C";
        }else if (functionNum == 1) {
            key = "D";
        }else if (functionNum == 2) {
            key = "E";
        }else if (functionNum == 3) {
            key = "F";
        }else if (functionNum == 4) {
            key = "G";
        }else if (functionNum == 5) {
            key = "A";
        }else if (functionNum == 6) {
            key = "B";
        }

        return key;
    }

    private String getCorrectBlackKeyForNumber (int number) {

        int functionNum = number;
        String key = "C#";

        while (functionNum > 4) {
            functionNum = functionNum - 5;
        }

        if (functionNum == 0) {
            key = "C#";
        }else if (functionNum == 1) {
            key = "D#";
        }else if (functionNum == 2) {
            key = "F#";
        }else if (functionNum == 3) {
            key = "G#";
        }else if (functionNum == 4) {
            key = "A#";
        }

        return key;
    }

    private int getCorrectOctavForNumber (int number) {

        int functionNum = number;
        int octave = 0;

        while (functionNum > 6) {
            octave = octave + 1;
            functionNum = functionNum - 7;
        }

        return octave;
    }

    private int getCorrectBlackOctavForNumber (int number) {

        int functionNum = number;
        int octave = 0;

        while (functionNum > 4) {
            octave = octave + 1;
            functionNum = functionNum - 5;
        }

        return octave;
    }

//    private TouchModel calculateTouchKey (Float touchX, Float touchY) {
//
//        int columWidth = width/COLUMS_COUNT;
//        int rowHeight = height/ROWS_COUNT;
//
//        int selectectColum = (int) Math.floor(touchX/columWidth)+1;
//        int selectectRow = (int) Math.floor(touchY/rowHeight)+1;
//
//        TouchModel touchModel = new TouchModel(selectectColum, selectectRow);
//
//
//        mainInterface.widgetTouched(selectectColum, selectectRow);
//
//        return touchModel;
//    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        switch(action){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchX = event.getX();
                touchY = event.getY();
                isTouching = true;

//                Log.d ("Testings", "Touch Event: "+event);
//                calculateTouchKey(touchX, touchY);
//                Log.d (TAG, "touched: "+touchX+" and: "+touchY);
//                Log.d (TAG, "x: "+selectedCells.touchX+" y: "+selectedCells.touchY);

                break;
            default:
                isTouching = false;
        }
        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

    public void initlizeWidgetVars (PianoKeysInterface chessBoardInterface) {
        mainInterface = chessBoardInterface;
        mainInterface.setChessArray(pianoPathsArray);
    }

    public void updateChessArray(ArrayList<ChessSlice> localChessArray) {
        pianoPathsArray = localChessArray;
        this.postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: you'd have better luck getting help if you posted less code. Post only the parts that are necessary to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

fixed it by :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < pianoPathsArray.size(); i++) {
                    RectF boundrySlice=new RectF();
                    pianoPathsArray.get(i).computeBounds(boundrySlice, true);

                    if(boundrySlice.contains(touchX,touchY)){
                        selectedPath= pianoPathsArray.get(i);// where selectedPath is declared Globally.
                    }

                }
```

Comment: finally got it, thank you soo much, now i get to know what actually mistake i was making,